# How to show the images from the path in which the photos are taken in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I try to get a list of images taken with the camera but I don't understand what I need to do to see the images, not the routes. I also don't know how I could transform those routes so that the images would be seen.

[screenshot of the blocks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI8Zu.png)
[image]

Comment: see the documentation of the listview component here http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/advanced-listview.html

Comment: you might want to ask in the App Inventor commuinity to get more help https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/